# Change first line number

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How to change first line number after call of constructor

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codemirror"), {
    firstLineNumber: 5 // how to change later?
});
```

use `editor.firstLineNumber = 10;` don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [doc](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_configuration), you can change configuration with that function: setOption.

So in you case, you can code:

```
editor.setOption('firstLineNumber', 10);
```